# R: Saving the arima values in a dataframe

Tags: r

I can find the arima values using:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- auto.arima(WWWusage)
plot(forecast(fit,h=20))
```

This gives an arima value 1,1,1
I would like to store the result in a dataframe but I cannot find the correct fit  object to do this:

```
 df1 <- fit$arimaobject
```

so that the dataframe cells df1 would hold the values 1 1 1

If arima values were 3, 1, 0
then the dataframe cells df1 would hold the values 3 1 0

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The values you want are the first 3 values of `fit$arma[c(1, 6, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5)]`.